# Django haystack filtering by foreign key id

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

I want to filter my search query by `default_category.pk`.

Here is my SearchIndex:

```
class ProductIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    content_auto = indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='content')
    default_category = indexes.IntegerField()

    def get_model(self):
        return Product

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

I tried both

`default_category = indexes.IntegerField(model_attr='default_category__pk')`

and

`def prepare_default_category(self, obj):
        return obj.default_category.pk`

Here is my view code

`products = SearchQuerySet().models(Product).filter(content=auto_query, default_category=category_id)`

But this queryset is empty. If I remove `default_category=category_id` from filter then the list is not empty. And if i try to see `dir(products[0])`, there are

`[…, amount', 'app_label', 'brand', 'category_id', 'content_type', 'default_category_id', 'description', 'distance', 'get_additional_fields', 'get_stored_fields', 'id', 'log', 'model', 'model_name', 'object', 'pk', 'price', 'sale', 'score', 'searchindex', 'shop_id', 'stored_fields', 'title', 'verbose_name', 'verbose_name_plural']`

So here are some fields, those not described in SearchIndex and field `default_category_id` (I don't know, where it is from, it seems to be always `None`).

What I do wrong here? Maybe I need to write something in `product_text.txt` or I don't understand something important?

I use django-1.9.8 and haystack version is `(2, 5, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was really obvious. I used `Simple` search backend. And this is what I found in official docs:

> This backend does NOT work like the other backends do. **Data preparation** does nothing & **advanced filtering** calls do not work. You really probably don’t want this unless you’re in an environment where you just want to silence Haystack.